# How to align button centered below table?

Tags: html, alignment, html-table

I put form elements in a table so that column names and inputs are aligned to 2-columns.
And I put submit button and cancel button below the table.
The table width is not fixed.
I want to put the buttons center-aligned of the table width.

One simple way is to put the buttons in the table.
But I want to separate them from the table.
What's the most elegant way to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Structure like this:

```
<div>
<!-- Your table -->
<table />
<!-- Your buttons -->
<div style="text-align:center;">
<input />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That wouldn't work: a DIV spans the max width available, while a table does not.

Comment: Oh well - directly said => "absolutely nice & wrong statement" :) -- easy to test by using an html editor of your choice --- just extend my provided snippet with a few properties to visualize the object boundaries ---- `<div>
<!-- Your table -->
<table width="100px;" border="1 1 1 1 solid green">
  <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
  </table>
<!-- Your buttons -->
<div style="text-align:center;border-width: 1px; border-color:red; border-style:solid;">
<input type="submit" /><input type="submit" /><input type="submit" />
</div>
</div>`
 The short answer: end of table is followed by line break

Answer (score 2):

Since the buttons and table are related you could use a fieldset:

```
<fieldset>
<!-- Your table -->
<table />
<!-- Your buttons -->
<p style="text-align:center;">
<input />
</p>
</fieldset>
```